# Changing Thumbnail Size

Tags: html, thumbnails

Here is a screenshot of what I want to change:
[image]

Here is a snippet of code I am guessing to change:

```
<div id="gallery" class="lbGallery" style="width: 680px">
        <ul>
          <div align="center">
            <div align="center">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div align="left">
            <div>&nbsp;<a href="http://pacificrollers.com/images/lightbox/kwokwah1.jpg" title=""><img alt="" title="" src="http://pacificrollers.com/images/lightbox/kwokwah1.jpg" border="0" height="200%" width="273%" /></a><br />
            </div>
          </div>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          </p>
          <p align="center"><a href="http://pacificrollers.com/images/lightbox/kwokwah2.jpg" title=""><img alt="" title="" src="http://pacificrollers.com/images/lightbox/kwokwah2.jpg" border="0" height="2483" width="1755" /></a>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          </p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <div align="center">&nbsp;</div>
          <p align="center"></p>
          <div align="center"></div>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

However, I'm not sure how to change the thumbnail size. I searched on Google and still had a tough time finding a consistent way to change it. I'm suspecting that I need to change the `<img>` tag contents, but not entirely sure.

Comment: You just want to change the size of an image?

Comment: Just the image shown in the page. I suppose it's the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<img />` elements.

...but there is no excuse for `<p align="center">`, seeing your HTML made me feel like I traveled back in time to 1999.

*Update:*

Looking at the screenshot, both images in the webpage have the same dimensions on-screen, despite having different attribute values. It's possible their size is specified by a stylesheet. Look for `img` in any referenced CSS or `<style>` blocks and consider deleting those rules or overriding them locally with the `style=""` attribute with the `!important` keyword.

Comment: It was't the 30 `p` elements in a row?

Comment: I changed those attributes already, but made no difference. This is the site I have to work with right now. In the process of moving it to Wordpress.

Comment: I have updated my response. I think a style rule is in-effect.

Answer (score 0):

`<p align="center"><a href="http://pacificrollers.com/images/lightbox/kwokwah2.jpg" title=""><img alt="" title="" src="http://pacificrollers.com/images/lightbox/kwokwah2.jpg" border="0" height="2483" width="1755" /></a>`

This has you setting the `height` and `width` to very large values. Could you try making them smaller?

**Note**: This will not make a true thumbnail, it will still load the entire image, but just shrink it down. If you would like to have an actual thumbnail, then you will need to create some kind of programatic way of shrinking images and providing a thumbnail sized image.

There is also quite a lot of worry about with the many many `<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>`s. You might want to look into styling this with CSS instead of hardcoding these linebreaks.